# Scrollview stops panning after zoom

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder

In my iOS 6.0+ app, I need to have a background image, and spots as overlay images. The spots should be draggable. And the whole background + overlays should scroll (horizontally and vertically) and zoom together as a unit.

I have the following view hierarchy:

```
- View
    + Scroll View "scrollView"
        + View "scrollingView"
            - Image View - Background
            + View "overlays"
                - Image View - Overlay 1
                - ...
                - Image View - Overlay n
```

Now the problem is, that the scrolling only works as long as I don't zoom - when I start to zoom, the content in the scroll view immediately scrolls back ("jumps") to the top left corner, zooming in/out works, but panning/scrolling does not work any longer.

In my ViewController, I set

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

and

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.scrollingView;
}
```

What do I need to do, to have both zooming and scrolling working?

Comment: When you say the scrollingView jumps, what do you mean? Does its frame change?

Comment: Ah sorry - no, if I scroll down (i.e. to the bottom right corner), the visible content (always) scrolls back immediately ("jumps") to the top left corner when I begin to zoom - the frame of the ScrollView stays where it is. 

(Edited description)

Comment: Try putting the image view as the direct child of the scroll view, removing the scrollingView and all the overlays, and making the requisite changes to -viewForZoomingInScrollView:. Does it still jump?